# Predicting words based on swiping a keyboard

Tags: c#

I thought this question was particularly interesting [DailyProgrammer 284: Wandering Fingers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142784/dailyprogrammer-284-wandering-fingers/142809) so thought I'd have a pop at it myself. See the other question for the nitty gritty but the brief problem statement is:

> You'll be given a string of characters representing the letters the user has dragged their finger over.
>
> For example, if the user wants "rest", the string of input characters might be "resdft" or "resert".
>
> ### Input
>
> Given the following input strings, find all possible output words 5 characters or longer.
>
> 1. qwertyuytresdftyuioknn
> 2. gijakjthoijerjidsdfnokg
>
> ### Output
>
> Your program should find all possible words (5+ characters) that can be derived from the strings supplied.
>
> Use http://norvig.com/ngrams/enable1.txt as your search dictionary.
>
> The order of the output words doesn't matter.
>
> 1. queen question
> 2. gaeing garring gathering gating geeing gieing going goring

I've made the assumption that this is the English alphabet (i.e. [a-z]) which is pretty normal for a qwerty keyboard.

I created a simple lookup class:

```
public class AutocompleteCache
{
    private readonly IList<string>[] cache = new IList<string>[26*26]; 

    public AutocompleteCache(IEnumerable<string> wordList)
    {
        if (wordList == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(wordList));
        }
        foreach (var word in wordList.Where(w => w.Length >= 5))
        {
            var index = CalculateIndex(word);
            var cachedWords = cache[index];
            if (cachedWords == null)
            {
                cache[index] = new List<string>();
            }
            cache[index].Add(word);
        }
    }

    private static int CalculateIndex(string word)
    {
        Debug.Assert(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(word));
        return (word[0] - 97)*26 + (word[word.Length - 1] - 97);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> SuggestWords(string input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        }
        var candidates = (cache[CalculateIndex(input)] ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>());
        return candidates.Where(candidate => CheckWordIsValidForInput(candidate, input));
    }

    private bool CheckWordIsValidForInput(string word, string input)
    {
        int currentPosition = 0;
        foreach (var c in word)
        {
            currentPosition = input.IndexOf(c, currentPosition);
            if (currentPosition == -1)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The responsibility of this class is to take a dictionary of words and sort it into an array of lists of words. The index of the array is determined by a simple calculation of the first and last letters of the word (`CalculateIndex`). Which gives us an O(1) lookup for the list of candidate words. This is the same complexity as using a dictionary would have but has smaller constant terms than using the dictionary. The overall algorithm is  O(n*m) with O(n) startup cost where n is the number of words and m is the length of the input string. The memory requirement is O(k^2) where k is the alphabet length (hard coded to 26 here).

I benchmarked this against the OP's solution and [Jonbot's dictionary](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/142813/22816) and found that for input 1 over 10000 iterations it's approximately twice as fast as Jobbot's and about 200 times faster than OPs solution. For words with a larger list of candidates, i.e. more common first and last letters, it ends up being only very slightly faster ~5% that the dictionary approach but still an order of magnitude faster than the OP.

Usage of the code:

```
 var words = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\some\path\to\dictionary.txt");
 var autoCompleteCache = new AutocompleteCache(words);
 var results = autoCompleteCache.SuggestWords("quen"); 
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", results)); // queen
```

Looking for any and all comments.

Comment: Clearly it has some problems

Comment: @Paparazzi what a completely pointless comment. If the problems are so clear to you, please would you spell them out to me? The only major issue I can see is that it is very coupled to the alphabet which I've already made note of.

Comment: Just wanted to reuse clearly as you used it in a comment to me.   I felt the need for the word was pointless also.

Comment: How come that's O(1) when you have loops + `Where`?

Comment: @denis - I didn't say the algorithm was O(1) I said: Which gives us an O(1) **lookup for the list of candidate words**. I'll edit the question to make that clearer.

Comment: @Paparazzi I wasn't upset by your use of the word "clearly" I felt that your comment was against the spirit of CR - i.e. reviewing code and explaining problems. I've looked at the comment I made on your answer: "Your code clearly doesn't even compile (*explanation of why it doesn't*)". I'd like to apologise for the way I phrased it as it clearly upset you. I still think I had a valid point, your code *didn't* compile which you've now fixed. I hope your comment was cathartic and made you feel better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks fine. Just some minor adjustments:

I think it would look even nicer if you defined constants for the magic numbers.

```
 const int AlphabetLength = 26;
 const int MinWordLength = 5;
```

In place of `97` I'd put simply an `'a'`.

---

Instead of

> ```
> currentPosition == -1
> ```

I suggest

```
currentPosition < 0
```

The `-1` looks like a magic number. I sometimes use a constant for it that I name `IndexOutOfRange`.

---

You use `var` everywhere but here :-)

> ```
> int currentPosition = 0;
> ```

---

It might also be a good idea to move the code from the constructor into a new method like `AddWords` or `AddWord` so you can extend the dictionary later if necessary. Usually those dictionaries can learn new words.

Comment: All very helpful comments thanks! I'm not sure how that `int` snuck in there ;)

Answer (score 0):

Below please find some comments and suggestions inline:

```
  public class AutocompleteCache
  {
    private readonly string[][] cache; // Why not a jagged array as it is a one time creation?
    private readonly int alphabetSize;

    // sizeOfAlphabet makes it usefull for other languages than english
    public AutocompleteCache(IEnumerable<string> wordList, int sizeOfAlphabet = 26)
    {
      if (wordList == null)
      {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(wordList));
      }

      alphabetSize = sizeOfAlphabet;

      //cache = new List<string>[alphabetSize * alphabetSize];
      cache = new string[alphabetSize * alphabetSize][];

      //foreach (var word in wordList.Where(w => w.Length >= 5))
      //{
      //  var index = CalculateKey(word);
      //  var cachedWords = cache[index];
      //  if (cachedWords == null)
      //  {
      //    cache[index] = new List<string>();
      //  }
      //  cache[index].Add(word);
      //}

      // You could use linq here:
      var groups = wordList.GroupBy(w => CalculateKey(w));
      foreach (var group in groups)
      {
        cache[group.Key] = group.ToArray();
      }
    }

    // Just for test
    public void PrintCache()
    {
      var min = cache.Where(arr => arr != null).Min(arr => arr.Length);
      var max = cache.Where(arr => arr != null).Max(arr => arr.Length);
      var avg = cache.Where(arr => arr != null).Average(arr => arr.Length);

      Console.WriteLine($"Min: {min} -> Max: {max} -> Average: {avg}");
    }

    // Why static if private?
    private /* static */ int CalculateKey(string word)
    {
      return (word[0] - 97) * alphabetSize + (word[word.Length - 1] - 97);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> SuggestWords(string input)
    {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();

      var key = CalculateKey(input);

      // You should check for valid key...
      if (key < 0 || key >= cache.Length)
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();

      // ... because an invalid key will cause an exception here
      //var candidates = (cache[CalculateKey(input)] ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>());
      //return candidates.Where(candidate => IsCandidateValid(candidate, input));

      // You know the key is in range here.
      return cache[key]?.Where(candidate => IsCandidateValid(candidate, input)) ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }

    private bool IsCandidateValid(string candidate, string input)
    {
      int currentPosition = 0;
      foreach (var c in candidate)
      {
        currentPosition = input.IndexOf(c, currentPosition);
        if (currentPosition == -1)
        {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
  }
```